# Wordpress child theme and files in folders

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

I've got a qustion - my footer.php file includes such a function:

```
<?php adios_footer_template(adios_get_opt('footer-template')); ?>
```

as I assumed the code was calling some internal function. When I've digged into the theme code I've found out that this function has a following code:

```
function adios_footer_template($layout) {
    if(class_exists('ReduxFramework') && !adios_get_opt('footer-enable-switch')) { return; }
    switch ($layout) {
      case 'footer-style5':
        get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style5');
        break;
      case 'footer-style4':
        get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style4');
        break;
      case 'footer-style3':
        get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style3');
        break;
      case 'alternative':
        get_template_part('templates/footer/alternative');
        break;
      case 'default':
      default:
        get_template_part('templates/footer/default');
        break;
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to OR add one more case via child theme and makes it work or simply have at least an option to edit those footer styles. What I've tried is to copy entire templates/footer directory into child theme and then add changes (without success; on frontend nothing has changed). THen I even tried to rename the function and paste it into my own functions.php, but again - didnt change anything. Is it even doable?

Comment: I know its obviously but have you checked adios_get_opt("footer-enable-switch is enabled")?

Comment: yes I have checked :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the function entirely in your child theme?

```
function adios_child_footer_template($layout) {
  # Line about adios_get_opt removed
  switch ($layout) {
    case 'footer-style5':
      get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style5');
      break;
    case 'footer-style4':
      get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style4');
      break;
    case 'footer-style3':
      get_template_part('templates/footer/footer-style3');
      break;
    case 'alternative':
      get_template_part('templates/footer/alternative');
      break;
    case 'default':
    default:
      get_template_part('templates/footer/default');
      break;
  }
}
```

And then calling it like:

```
<?php adios_child_footer_template('alternative'); ?>
```

My guess is that **adios_get_opt** is choosing a switch case that you didn't expect. Of course, this is only a shortcut. A better choice would be to find a way to properly extend the function AND add your footer style to **adios_get_opt**.

Comment: I've did it - nothing happened :O